# Adding a popup on Google maps markers flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

how would i add a popup to show details about a particular marker on google maps when clicked or tapped using flutter/dart. have tried using onTap function but gives me errors any ideas on how i can achieve this

```
populateHospitals() {
    Hospitals = []; //array to obtain individual hospital data
    Firestore.instance.collection('markers').getDocuments().then((docs) {
      if (docs.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          hospitalsToggle = true;
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {
          Hospitals.add(docs.documents[i].data);
          initMarker(docs.documents[i].data);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  initMarker(hospitals) {
    mapController.clearMarkers().then((val) {
      mapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
          position:
              LatLng(hospital['location'].latitude, hospital['location'].longitude),// draws the markers of the hospitals
              draggable: false, // disables dragging of the marker
              consumeTapEvents: true,
              infoWindowText: InfoWindowText(hospital['hospitalname'], 'hospital'), //displays the hospitals name when the icon is clicked

              ));


    });
  }
```

Comment: Marker has onTap function you can use that without specifying InfoWindow !

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Read more at source code at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart

```
 List <Marker> markers = new List<Marker>();

//Run the loop and add locations to marker 


markers.add(
            Marker(
                markerId: <SOMEID>,
                position: LatLng(hospital['location'].latitude, hospital['location'].longitude),


                onTap: () {
                  //this is what you're looking for!
                  print(hospital['hospitalname']);


                }
            )

        );

//Now add this to your map.
```